# Can I add a wrapper to my layout that has a pure CSS dynamic sticky footer?

Tags: html, css

After countless hours trying to find a way to implement a sticky footer with fluid height without resorting to using javascript, I finally found a way. No matter how much content I add to the `.footer`, it remains stuck to the bottom of the viewport, regardless of whether there is enough in the `.content` div to push it down. None of the javascript solutions I tried worked as smoothly as this, and I'd like to keep using this method if possible.

My problem is that due to an issue with various mobile browsers not accepting the `overflow-x:hidden;` rule on the `body` tag, I'm now having to add a wrapper to my layout. This fixes the mobile browser issue, but unfortunately stops the `.footer` from sticking to the bottom of the viewport when the `.content` div is empty.

I have of course tried to move several of the CSS rules from the body to the wrapper to see if this works, but I haven't had any success. Is there a way around this?

Here are two jsFiddle examples to show the problem, one with a `.wrapper` and one without.

**Example 1: Without wrapper (Sticky footer works)** – https://jsfiddle.net/v5h2f5wd/

**Example 2: With wrapper (Sticky footer does not work)** – https://jsfiddle.net/v5h2f5wd/1/

**Code from Example 2:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header"></header>
        <div class="content">
            <button>Click here to insert content into footer.</button>
        </div>
    <footer class="footer"></footer>
</div>

html {
    position:relative; 
    height:100%;
}

body {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    overflow-x:hidden;
    background-color:#eee;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:55px;
    background-color:#fff;
}

.content {
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    -webkit-flex:1;
    -ms-flex:1;
    flex:1;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:pink;
}

button { 
    margin:65px 0 0 10px;
} 

.footer {
    width:100%; 
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:25px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple with flexbox. No need for positioning at all.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  background: pink;
}

footer {
  background: red;
  padding: 1em;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>HEADER</header>
  <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique facere consequatur officiis cupiditate sed blanditiis magni sequi ducimus cum illum repellat ab nostrum excepturi aperiam dolor repudiandae mollitia, eius deleniti.</p>
  </main>
  <footer>FOOTER</footer>
  </div
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I actually did have a div called `.content` between my header and footer, with the `flex:1` property assigned to it. It also doesn't solve the problem I'm facing regarding adding a wrapper to the site, which I need to do for reasons I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Ooops..sorry I missed that...fixed. You just need nested flex-containers.

Comment: Not sure why our answers are being downvoted (they're the same) as they seem to meet the criteria, so I upvoted yours to fix the injustice. ; P

Comment: Thanks for this – there are some very good answers on here but this one ticks every box. It doesn't break the mobile layout at all. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `flexbox` solution.

Looks like you were trying to do something similar. The key points in this setup are `height: 100%;` on the `html` element (inherits from viewport height), `min-height: 100%;` on `body` element (inherits from `html` height) and `flex-grow: 1;` on `main` element (tells element to take up remaining space inside the container element).

With this solution the footer's height is dynamic which saves you the headache of have to update selectors in your stylesheet if it ever changes.

The JS in the solution is simply for demo purposes.

```js
var btnC   = document.querySelector( '.btn-c' );
var btnF   = document.querySelector( '.btn-f' );
var main   = document.querySelector( 'main' );
var footer = document.querySelector( 'footer' );

function addContent( target, str ) {

    var p = document.createElement( 'p' );

    p.innerHTML = str;

    target.appendChild( p );

}

btnC.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {

  for ( var i = 0, len = 5; i < len; i++ ) {
    addContent( main, 'Content' );
  }

} );

btnF.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {
    addContent( footer, 'Footer' );  
} );
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: gold;
}
main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
footer {
  background-color: indianred;
}
.wrap {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <header>
    Header
  </header>
  <main>
    <p>
      Content
    </p>
    <button class="btn-c">Add to Content</button>
    <br>
    <button class="btn-f">Add to Footer</button>
  </main>
  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

No need to do all the positioning (unnecessary) and width declarations (those elements already take up 100% width because they're block level elements).

Comment: Please comment on reason for down vote. Especially if it was the OP. What doesn't work properly?

Comment: Hi, it wasn't actually me that down-voted this – I appreciate that everybody on here is trying to help, so I don't down-vote suggestions from others. Unfortunately however, the answer doesn't solve my problem that I mentioned in my question – it's important that I'm able to add a wrapper around my content div for compatibility with mobile devices. This was possibly my fault for confusing everyone with the jQuery function in the footer – I was trying to highlight why I needed the flex layout to work in the same way and add a wrapper at the same time.

Comment: I think the reason people left out the wrapper element was because it seemed like it was a workaround for not being able to use `overflow-x: hidden;` on `body` along with a long round-about way of executing a sticky footer. So you got a standard flexbox sticky footer solution. Anywho, I've updated my answer. Basically moved the flex stuff from `body` to `.wrap`, moved `min-height: 100%;` to `.wrap` and added `height: 100%;` to `body`.

Answer (score 0):

So all I did was slightly alter the CSS you had in your JSFiddle, and the reason why what you had didn't work was that you needed to apply the same structuring styles to the parent containers since they need to be the same.

To get the footer to stick to the bottom I just used the align-self flex property to position it at the end of the parent flex element.

Hopefully this will work for you.

```
html {
  position:relative; 
  height:100%;
}
body, 
.wrapper{
  height: 100%; /* this makes sure that the body matches the window and the wrapper matches the body. */
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column
}
body {
  position:relative;
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  overflow-x:hidden;
  background-color:#eee;
}

.header {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:55px;
  background-color:#fff;
}

.content {
  -webkit-box-flex:1;
  -webkit-flex:1;
  -ms-flex:1;
  flex:1;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background-color:pink;
}

button { 
  margin:65px 0 0 10px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-item-align: end;
  align-self: flex-end; /* This puts it at the end of the parent flex element. */
  background-color:#fff;
  padding:25px 0;
}
```

Comment: `align-self: flex-end;` doesn't do anything here (remove it and see). What's actually pushing `.footer` to the bottom is 1) `.wrapper` having `display: flex;` and `.content` has `flex: 1;` which tells it to take up the remaining space of it's parent element.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use it with your wrapper, maybe this would work for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".footer").append("Some text to make me taller.");
    });
});
```

```css
html {
  position:relative; 
 height:100%;
  height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
}

body {
 position:relative;
  height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
 width:100%;
 min-height:100%;
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
 overflow-x:hidden;
 background-color:#eee;
 display:-webkit-box;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  height:100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:55px;
  background-color:#fff;
}

.content {
  -webkit-box-flex:1;
 -webkit-flex:1;
 -ms-flex:1;
 flex:1;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
  background-color:pink;
  height: 100%;
}

button { 
  margin:65px 0 0 10px;
}

.footer {
  width:100%; 
 background-color:#fff;
  padding:25px 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 
 <header class="header"></header>
  <div class="content">
    <button>Click here to insert content into footer.</button>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>

</div>
```

Comment: Why all the repeated and unnecessary properties? OP already had `height: 100%;` on `html`, no need to add zero padding/margin to `html`, repeated `height: 100%;` twice on `body` when there's `min-height: 100%;`, repeated margin/padding twice on `body` when there was `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;` to start, and added a second height on `.content`. Not to mention `.container` doesn't expand properly with enough content and the footer overlays said content, **[see this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dz2khotf/)**.

Comment: @hungstar - I know that there are some repeated properties - its a draft to see the sticky footer work with a wrapper div. Problem was that the `.wrapper` has no height property.

Comment: That's not a proper reason to duplicate properties. It takes almost no effort to not duplicate. Besides, you're ignoring the bigger issue with your solution that was noted before, **[it doesn't work properly](https://jsfiddle.net/dz2khotf/)**.